# Align image with form

Tags: html, css

I need to leave the image aligned with the form according to the photo below, being the site responsive, could anyone give me some advice?

[image]

but i wanted it to stay that way

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style>
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;    
  }
  body{
    
  }
  input {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  }
  .container {
    width: 360px;
    padding: 8% 0 0;
    margin: auto;        
  }
  .ContainerTodos{
    background-image: url('../../assets/undraw_unexpected_friends_tg6k.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: right,center;
    height: 98vh; 
    
  }
  #Capa_1{
    width: 25px;
    margin:auto;
    color: #111213;
    
  }
  #logo{
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -180px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #Layer_1{
    width: 25px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 8px;
  }
  .iconUser{
    margin:auto;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
  }

  .cls-1{fill:#111213;}
  .cls-2{fill:#0c52eb;}
  form {
    caret-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    max-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
    padding: 45px;
    border-radius:45px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  }
  form input{

  }
  input:-webkit-autofill,
  input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
  input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
  input:-webkit-autofill:active,
  input:-webkit-autofill::first-line {  
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #f0f0f0 inset;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(36, 31, 31) !important;
  }
  /* input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow:#f0f0f0 inset;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: blue !important;
  } */
   
  .btn {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    outline: 0;
    background: #0c52eb;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-radius:30px;
    margin: 0px 0px 8px;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
    transition: all 0.3 ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    margin-top: 10px;
  } 
  .title{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .input-field{
    max-width: 380px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    margin: 10px 0;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 55px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 15% 70% 15%;
    padding: 0 0.4rem;
    position: relative;
  }
  .input-field input{
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: rgb(36, 31, 31);
  }
    
  .input-field-password{
    max-width: 380px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    margin: 10px 0;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 55px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 15% 70% 15%;
    padding: 0 0.4rem;
    position: relative;          
  }
  .input-field-password input{
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: rgb(36, 31, 31);
  }
  .input-field input::placeholder {
    color: #aaa;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .iinput-field-password input::placeholder {
    color: #aaa;
    font-weight: 600;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    #logo{
      width: 70px;
      height: 70px;
      margin-left: auto;
    }      
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    form{
      margin-top:60px;
      width: 340px;
      height: 300px;
    }
    
  }  
  @media screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
    .ContainerTodos{
      background-position: bottom 5px right 10px;
    }    
  }
   
</style>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ContainerTodos">
      
        <div class="container">
          <img id="logo" src="./2bdc78b6c227760fca29334de506d739.jpg"
            alt="The head and torso of a dinosaur skeleton;
                  it has a large head with long sharp teeth">
            <div class="form">
                <form @submit.prevent="submit" class="sign-in-form" >
                        <h2 class="title">Entrar</h2>
                        <div class="input-field">                       
                           <img id="Capa_1" src="data:image/png;base64,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">                        
                           <input type="text" placeholder="Username"  v-model="login.VarUsernameLogin"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field-password">
                          <img id="Capa_1" src="data:image/png;base64,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">                        
                          <input :type="eyeOfSupermanInscrever? 'text':'password'" placeholder="Password" v-model="login.VarPasswordLogin"/>
                          <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 128 128" @click="feyeOfSupermanInscrever()"><defs>
                           </defs><title>v</title><path class="cls-1" d="M125.088,63.50318l-.79374-.89873a81.072,81.072,0,0,0-103.03269-14.682A81.32084,81.32084,0,0,0,3.6897,62.6316l-.73944.83854A6.23766,6.23766,0,0,0,2.934,71.85331l.78017.87429A81.47074,81.47074,0,0,0,21.25974,87.42768a3.7072,3.7072,0,1,0,3.9135-6.29745A74.05513,74.05513,0,0,1,9.235,67.77916l-.10046-.11268.086-.09684A73.92274,73.92274,0,0,1,25.17324,54.22037,73.65946,73.65946,0,0,1,118.75976,67.538l.114.12852-.09141.10227a75.15449,75.15449,0,0,1-5.48017,5.48017,73.46381,73.46381,0,0,1-10.47071,7.86864,3.707,3.707,0,0,0,3.90264,6.30378,80.90992,80.90992,0,0,0,11.53506-8.66782,82.48721,82.48721,0,0,0,6.03588-6.03815l.76478-.85664A6.26251,6.26251,0,0,0,125.088,63.50318Z" id="id_105" style="fill: rgb(5, 5, 5);"></path><path class="cls-2" d="M78.50979,71.50758A12.50668,12.50668,0,0,1,65.99816,58.99595a12.35073,12.35073,0,0,1,1.29752-5.54217,19.22026,19.22026,0,0,0-3.29014-.2873A19.50425,19.50425,0,1,0,83.50519,72.66606a18.19881,18.19881,0,0,0-.12049-2.14088A12.5099,12.5099,0,0,1,78.50979,71.50758Z" id="id_106"></path></svg>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn solid"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```